# Docker error returned a non-zero code: 1 while building docker image

Tags: linux, docker, unzip

When I try to build the docker, I get an error like "/bin/sh -c returned a non-zero code: 1 ".

Here is the dockerfile which I have created

```
FROM tomcat:7.0.82-jre8
WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat
COPY /app.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get install -y dos2unix 
RUN unzip /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war -d /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app
EXPOSE 8080
COPY tomcat-users.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
COPY test1.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app/conf/services/
COPY doc.properties /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app/conf/services/properties/
COPY springConfig.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app/conf/quartz/
COPY test.properties /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app/conf
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2G -Xmx2G"
# Copy Entrypoint script in the container
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh / 
RUN dos2unix /docker-entrypoint.sh && apt-get --purge remove -y dos2unix && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

When I try to build the docker image based on the above dockerfile, I get an error like this

```
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c unzip /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war -d /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I am not sure what is causing this issue. I went through couple of stackoverflow posts with similar kind of error and tried those solutions, but no luck on that. Between this dockerfile was working before, but for some reason I get this error now.

Any help on this would be appreciable.

Comment: Run a build again; take the last good cache id and do a `docker run -it cache_id_here /bin/sh` and then try running that `unzip` command. You'll find out your error.

Comment: @TJBiddle i am not sure what is that cache id here ? how do you get that ?

Comment: I think you mean to say the imageId ..

Comment: It worked, i got the issue by doing that way. Thanks @TJBiddle

Comment: what was the solution